# Linux Kernel coding style

Tags: c, linux, coding-style, linux-kernel

I am new in the kernel-programming, so I would like to find out what coding style is more acceptable. For example, in case of the error handling which of the following is better?

This one:

```
/* some stuff */
if(error) {
    /* error handling */
    return -(errorcode);
}
/* normal actions */
```

or this one:

```
/* some stuff */
if(!error) {
    /* normal actions */
} else {
    /* error handling */
    return -(errorcode);
}
```

Where can I find any document, that regards to kernel coding standard?

Comment: http://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle

Comment: And to elaborate on ouah's Most Excellent reply: your first snippet is "preferred" over the second.  But the main point is to use K & R style (vs. .Net or Java or - heaven forbid - MS "Hungarian" coding styles) ;)

Comment: And add space after "if" :) http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.6.1/Documentation/CodingStyle#L179 , When it comes to coding style in general I have used that document as base for all coding in C - not only kernel-coding and found it invaluable.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Linux kernel has a coding style guide:

https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/process/coding-style.rst

[Nicer Formatted Version](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/process/coding-style.html)

Regarding your example, I personally prefer the first style. With the second style you will quickly violate this Linux kernel style rule (kernel style has 8-character indentation):

> if you need more than 3 levels of indentation, you're screwed anyway, and should fix
> your program.

Writing code from top to bottom (as opposed to horizontally) is sometimes referred as *duffing*. I can suggest you this excellent reading on the subject:

[Reading Code From Top to Bottom](http://iq0.com/notes/deep.nesting.html)

Comment: Thank you for the reference to the Reading Code From Top to Bottom article. It is indeed an excellent one.

Comment: HTML link: https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v4.10/process/coding-style.html